# Unable to run Ionic app after update to Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic3

Here's my Ionic Info

> cli packages: (/Users/billb/dev/customer-mkt-app/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.15.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.15.2
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.1
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.3.0
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
ios-deploy        : 1.9.2
Node              : v6.11.5
npm               : 3.10.10
OS                : macOS Sierra
Xcode             : Xcode 9.0.1 Build version 9A1004
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : /Users/billb/Library/Android/sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

I can successfully build the app. When I try to open it in Android Studio, I get a handful of errors, mostly around a gradle sync failure. Here's the 5 errors in the Messages console.

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :CordovaLib.
>   Could not resolve project :CordovaLib.
>
> Required by:
>       project :
>
> Project : declares a dependency from configuration 'debugCompile' to configuration 'debug' which is not declared in the descriptor for project >:CordovaLib.

---

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :CordovaLib.
>   Could not resolve project :CordovaLib.
>
> Required by:
>       project :
>
> Project : declares a dependency from configuration 'debugCompile' to configuration 'debug' which is not declared in the descriptor for project >:CordovaLib.

---

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :CordovaLib.
>   Could not resolve project :CordovaLib.
>
> Required by:
>       project :
>
> Project : declares a dependency from configuration 'debugCompile' to configuration 'debug' which is not declared in the descriptor for project >
>   :CordovaLib.

---

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :CordovaLib.
>
> Could not resolve project :CordovaLib.
>   Required by:
>       project :
>
> Project : declares a dependency from configuration 'releaseCompile' to configuration 'release' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :CordovaLib.

---

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :CordovaLib.
>
> Could not resolve project :CordovaLib.
>   Required by:
>       project :
>
> Project : declares a dependency from configuration 'releaseCompile' to configuration 'release' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :CordovaLib.

I really don't know what this means and Google hasn't turned up anything of any real help. What do I need to do here?

**Note:** discovered this after posting this. Relaying it here in case it will help someone else.

[Don't upgrade to Android Studio 3](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/google-released-android-studio-3-0-you-should-probably-not-upgrade-yet-as-cordova-is-not-ready-yet-but-working-on-it/109967/2)

Comment: Android Gradle plugin 3 has some regressions so I suggest to use Android Studio 3 but do not upgrade Gradle plugin in your Cordova project.

Comment: I had already updated everything. I learned my lesson. go check all the sources before updating things.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

I commented the lines below in the build.gradle file:

```
//debugCompile project(path: 'CordovaLib', configuration: 'debug') 

//releaseCompile project(path: 'CordovaLib', configuration: 'release')
```

and added:

```
compile project(':CordovaLib')
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Plus one here. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me!!

Comment: Worked for me tooo

Comment: when I run ionic cordova run android again my gradle.build is overwritten. This doesn't work for me...

Comment: If you get the warning "WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'" then simply replace 'compile' with 'implementation'

Answer (score 18):

If you are using Cordova build.gradle is automatically generated and when you next build the project the change in accepted answer above get overwritten back to the old that doesn't work.

So edit platforms/android/cordova/lib/builder/GradleBuiler.js
Comment out lines 136-139 and add the next line

```
/*depsList += '    debugCompile(project(path: "' + libName + '", configuration: "debug"))';
insertExclude(p);
depsList += '    releaseCompile(project(path: "' + libName + '", configuration: "release"))';
insertExclude(p);
    */
    depsList += "    compile project(':CordovaLib')";
    insertExclude(p);
```

Comment: This is the winning solution for me that allows continual builds without having the build.gradle file getting overwritten

Comment: This is exactly what i needed too, due to GradleBuilder.js overwriting the changes mentioned in other answers

Answer (score 11):

If you get this kind of error in Android Studio 3.0.1:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for :@debug/compileClasspath’: Could not resolve project :CordovaLib.
```

Go to `build.gradle` file -> find dependencies and change it like this

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    //debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    //releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
    compile project(':CordovaLib')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

Answer (score 10):

This is a known problem you can find the related jira issue [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13289) and the underlying problem is [this one](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11244) and both are "in progress". And there is already a [pull request on github](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/pull/413) which you can try out but I can't promise you that it is already a working version. You can install it like this if you would like to try that:

```
cordova platform add https://github.com/infil00p/cordova-android.git#StudioThreeFix
```

Answer (score 4):

Add this in Android build .gradle dependencies. That's all.

```
compile project(':CordovaLib')
```

For example:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    //debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    //releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
    compile project(':CordovaLib')
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So, I just spent two days battling this and came-up with a semi-manual solution.

Because Gradle decided to uproot it's dependency format without any grace period for migration, we're forced to do things like this.

(Instructions under Linux. For Windows you'd need some 7zip or something similar for the last step)

From your user home directory go to `.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android`.
In there, there should be one or more folders with version numbers.
Usually only the latest version is run.
Open it.
Delete the `package` directory, but **not** the `package.tgz` file.
Unpack the `package.tgz` file, then delete it, or move it to a backup location. (there are some extra files generated that we don't want to re-package later)
Edit the file `package/bin/templates/cordova/lib/plugin-build.gradle` and inside `dependencies` remove these lines

```
debugCompile project(path: ":CordovaLib", configuration: "debug")
releaseCompile project(path: ":CordovaLib", configuration: "release")
```

Replace them with

```
implementation project(path: ":CordovaLib")
```

Archive the package directory. In Linux the short command is `tar czf package.tgz package`. On Windows, you'd have to create a `.tar.gz` archive with 7zip and rename it to `.tgz`.

After that, in running a `cordova prepare` in a clean repository that worked with the old versions will work again, unless some of the plugins explicitly use the old declaration format and need to be updated ([example](https://github.com/agamemnus/cordova-plugin-xapkreader/issues/116))

Comment: What I don't quite get is why this isn't fixed in cordova-android itself? Surely other people are having this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i found a solution.

I was using cordova-android: 6.3.0. I updated the version to 7.1.0 and then changed this line in the config.xml

before was:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
```

Now i'm using:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
```

This way, `ionic cordova` run android is working again without having to change those lines in `build.gradle`!

Comment: Worked for me. Follow this steps to save your time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you are facing this type of problem, you just de-grade the gradle version to 2.2.3 and re-sync the project it will work.

Answer (score 0):

**Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018.**

Simply replace 'compile' with 'implementation'

```
dependencies {
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    //debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    //releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
    implementation project(':CordovaLib')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```