# GradleBuilder.js replacing build.gradle

Tags: android, cordova, android-gradle-plugin, ionic3, build.gradle

I'm trying to do cordova build android, it fails with

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':debugCompileClasspath'.
>   Could not resolve project :CordovaLib.
>        Required by:
>            project :
>   Project : declares a dependency from configuration 'debugCompile' to configuration 'debug' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :CordovaLib.

I came to know that if I replace these two lines

```
debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
```

with this in android studio(directly in build.gradle)

```
compile project(':CordovaLib')
```

then it works, I mean it builds. But as the project is in Ionic / Cordova, when I try to build it with cordova build android, it fails with above error again, as the changes gets overwritten by Gradlebuilder.js file back to the above 2 lines debug & releasecompile.

I want to know what & where should I make changes in gradlebuilder.js, so I get those 2 lines replaced by

```
compile project(':CordovaLib')
```

Any help is appreciated.

[Check Manmohan Pal's answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47023068/unable-to-run-ionic-app-after-update-to-android-studio-3-0/47257535)

Answer (score 0):

I know that your question was 9 months ago, but I have the same problem and I have resolved the problem.

So, like you says, with Cordova the file `build.gradle` always override again and delete the new line `compile project(':CordovaLib')`.

Well, the solution is modify the builder gradle in the path `{PROJECT}/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js` and you must be to find the lines `debugCompile`, `releaseCompile` and comment and write the new line.

[image]